# How to implement custom [Ignore] attribute for unit tests? (Skip some tests in RELEASE configuration)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, mstest

I'm using MSTEST. I wish to tag test methods with the [TestWithCheats] attribute. These tests should be skipped without failing if they are run in the RELEASE configuration. However, they must be executed when in DEBUG configuration.

I tried using *Assert.Inconclusive* in test method, but it always throw an exception.

```
public static class TestHelpers
{
    public static void SkipIfCheatsNotAllowed()
    {
        #if !ALLOW_CHEATS
        Assert.Inconclusive("Skipping cheat tests in Release mode.");
        #endif
    }
}

TestHelpers.SkipIfCheatsNotAllowed();
```

So the main problem is these tests failed in jenkins.

```
Failed TriggerFreeSpinsRejectCashout [2 ms]

Error Message: Assert.Inconclusive failed. 

Skipping cheat test in Release configuration.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the approach I usually take in these situations:

1. Decorate the test with a category

```
[TestCategory("SkipInOfficialBuild")]
public static void SkipIfCheatsNotAllowed() 
{
...
}
```

2. Configure your build pipeline not to run tests with this category. I don't have experience with Maven but if it uses `dotnet test` it should look something like this:

```
dotnet test --filter TestCategory!=SkipInOfficialBuild
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can test decorated with 2 [TestCategory] attributes?

Comment: yes, you can put more than one TestCategory attribute on a test